# Magento 2.3 slow with over 200 Items

Tags: magento2.3, shopping-cart

https://9a1843a442.nxcli.net/

If you add more than 100 products cart almost does not load quickly, superslow. after adding 800 cart items, Cart page stop loading and took 3 min to come up. its magento optimize hosing with redis.

Anyone having same issue? Its magento 2.3.

Comment: I have the same problem, do you have an answer from now on?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, do you have an answer from now on?